# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tableplayers": syntax error (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

The following error occurs when I click on insert Button

CustomOpenHelper.java

```
public class CustomOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "players";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_SCORE = "score";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table" + TABLE_NAME
        + "(" + COLUMN_ID + "integer primary key autoincrement,"
        + COLUMN_NAME +"text not null,"
        + COLUMN_SCORE +"integer not null);";


public CustomOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}
```

logcat

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tableplayers": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create tableplayers(_idinteger primary key autoincrement,nametext not null,scoreinteger not null);

How to fix this problem?

Comment: You need to add a space after the keyword `table`. `"create table " + TABLE_NAME`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a space (' ') between `table` and `TABLE_NAME` in your create command.

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME
        + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
        + COLUMN_NAME +" text not null,"
        + COLUMN_SCORE +" integer not null);";
```

notice the added space in `"create table "` and before the datatype of each `column`.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use the **create table if not exists** instead of **create table**. And also give space between the create table and the "(". After modification the query should look like

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table if not exists " + TABLE_NAME
        + " (" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
        + COLUMN_NAME +" text not null,"
        + COLUMN_SCORE +" integer not null);";
```

Comment: Add space between table name and "("

Comment: `And also give space between the create table and the "(".` - USELESS. It's just a beautification **for readability, not a functional requirement**.